# Set the remote branch pushed to by default

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-config

I want to setup the `push` default remote branch for my local branch.

Eg, I want my local branch `main` to `push` to `origin/master`.

I've tried:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

But this only works for `fetch` / `pull`.  For `push`, I still need to do:

```
git push origin main:master
```

How can I set it up so that I only need to do a simple `git push`?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. `push` **all** the repo's branches to where they get pulled from via [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-pushdefault)
2. Per-branch config via [`remote.<name>.push`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpush)

---

To have **all** your repo's branches push to the branch that they pull from, use:

```
git config --local push.default upstream
```

Note: this will affect other branches, also.

---

To setup a single branch's remote push pair (Example: local `main` to `origin/master`):

1. Set the branch's remote

   ```
    git branch --set-upstream-to origin
   ```
2. Set the remote's push mapping

   ```
   git config --local remote.origin.push main:master
   ```